# Handling persistence of files(json) in low memory devices and sending them to server

Tags: ios, swift

#### Here is my scenario:

I have a small json file which I generate when the user opens the app and that needs to be sent to the server whenever the user minimizes or terminates the application.
My current logic includes creating a folder inside Application Support Directory, lets call it Test, during app startup and store the json file inside it. Once I send the file to the server I delete it.
This works for most of the users except ones with low memory in which case the OS doesnt allow me to create a folder and save files. This cause most of the information I need, to be dropped.

#### Here are my alternatives

- Use a combination of on disk and in-memory to store the files.
- Use `UserDefaults` maybe.

#### Here is my code to create a folder/save files

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
    if let documentDirectory = fileManager.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory,
                                                in: .userDomainMask).first {
      let folderURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent(storeName)
      if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: folderURL.path) {
        do {
          try fileManager.createDirectory(atPath: folderURL.path,
                                          withIntermediateDirectories: true,
                                          attributes: nil)
        } catch {
          print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

```
encodedData!.write(to: pathAsURL, options: .atomic)
```

I am clueless on how to reduce the loss here and any help would be welcome.

Comment: How big is the JSON?  Why do you write it to disk?  Why don't you simply send the data from memory?  When you say low memory, are you referring to your app being terminated when suspended due to memory pressure? Or are you referring to device disk space?

Comment: say its ~1KB and when i say low memory its device disk space. I am concerned about losing the data on network error and that is why i try to persist it so that i can resend it the next time.

Comment: Ok, but if the device can't store a 1kb file then the owner probably has bigger issues.